# html dom for td element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do I call the td element of a html table from the dom? document.getElementById("exampleTable").childNodes[] Should give you all of the tr elements, but how do you go two levels down? I'm to make a loop to read the text node of each td element in the table

Comment: You can use JQuery, it's much better than accessing the DOM directly. If you don't want to be frequently frustrated, don't use the DOM directly. Never. Ever.

Comment: Assuming exampleTable is the id of a `table` element created from HTML mark-up, document.getElementById("exampleTable").childNodes[] will return the `caption`, `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` elements, not `tr` elements.

Comment: @LajosArpad That's total FUD. Completely untrue.

Without seeing the HTML, I'd try:

[table].tBodies[0].rows, then loop through the rows, then [row].cells until you get what you're looking for. Since you haven't posted the HTML, you're doing yourself a great disservice. Please post it.

Comment: Avoid using TD/TR , it is not a good approach, use div

Comment: @KitHo It's impossible to make this statement without knowing what kind of data is being represented. If the data being displayed is a table, then an HTML table should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("exampleTable").getElementsByTagName("td")
```

that will return a NodeList of all `td`s in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those child nodes will have child nodes too, so getting the childnodes of each TR, will give you all TDs.

But if you're going to do DOM querying or DOM manipulation, I strongly suggest using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
var int_tr_start = 0;

var arr_tr = []; // store all tr's

arr_tr =  document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var TR = int_tr_start; TR < arr_tr.length; TR ++) { // for each td

  for (var TD = 0; TD < arr_tr[TR].childNodes.length; TD++) { //  for each tr
 var tc = (arr_tr.textContent) ? arr_tr[TR].childNodes[TD].textContent : arr_tr[TR].childNodes[TD].innerText; // store the text from with in cell
 alert(tc);
  }
}
```